# Error A pointer parameter does not point to accessible memory

Tags: c#, cen-xfs

i'm build apps using CEN XFS Standard, then i got this error `WFS_ERR_INVALID_POINTER` in CEN XFS document it was meaning like this `A pointer parameter does not point to accessible memory.` but i dont know what this error,,

my WFSExecute like this :

`WFSExecute(lphService, 1401, cardDispense, 0, lppResult);`

and my lppResult like this :

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit), Serializable]
    public struct WFSResult
    {
        [FieldOffset(0), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public uint RequestID;

        [FieldOffset(4), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
        public ushort hService;

        [FieldOffset(6), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 16)]
        public Timestamp tsTimestamp;

        [FieldOffset(22), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public int hResult;

        [FieldOffset(26), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwCommandCode;

        [FieldOffset(26), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public UInt32 dwEventID;

        [FieldOffset(30), MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
        public Int32 lpBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve], even though we cannot really compile or test it it is important to see all the types involved. Right we'll have to guess what the signature of that WFSExecute method is, and the types of lphService, cardDispense, and lppResult, and how you arrived at the values for those parameters.

Comment: For starters, there is no visible pointer in the posted code, so it's all guess work.

Comment: Could it be `lpbuffer`? "lp" = long pointer? If so, how do you calculate that value from C#? Or will that be filled by the code you call?

Comment: lphService and cardDispense is just string, so i think is not effect with my error...

Comment: lp is name from CEN XFS document so its no problem with that, my problem i think is with that structure..

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Can you post the type as it is declared in the CEN XFS documentation, or in its header files or wherever you have the real declaration of it?

Comment: sorry its my fault cz i'm not passing my param with pointer..so its error..ty